# form_tag: keep values of many text_filed_tag in params[]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, haml

I have the following form_tag:

```
  - @invoice_data.each do |data|
    %br
    = label_tag "Description"
    %br
    = text_field_tag 'item[description]', data.position
    %br
    = label_tag 'Quantity'
    %br
    = text_field_tag 'item[quantity]', data.num_event
    %br
    = label_tag 'Single Preis'
    %br
    = text_field_tag 'item[single_preis]', data.billable_fees / data.num_event
    %br
    = label_tag 'Vat Percent'
    %br
    = text_field_tag 'item[vat_percent]', "19"
  %br
  %div
    %br
    = submit_tag "add", class: 'btn btn-sm btn-default', style: 'margin-left: 5px; margin-top: -2px', type: 'submit'
```

That **form_tag** is creating as many fields as the number of records in @invoice_data (which is a result of a query), but after **submitting** my **params[]** only stores the last record of **@invoice_data**:`<ActionController::Parameters {"utf8"=>"✓", "item"=><ActionController::Parameters {"description"=>"Payment 4", "quantity"=>"1", "single_preis"=>"$0.26", "vat_percent"=>"19"} permitted: true>, "commit"=>"add", "controller"=>"comercio", "action"=>"send_invoice", "id"=>"1"} permitted: true>`

What should I do to store in params[] all the records in @invoice_data and not only the last of them?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The Rails way to create a necord along with nested children is by using nested attributes:

```
class Invoice < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :items
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :items
end

class Item < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :invoice
end
```

```
= form_with(model: @invoice) do |form|
  = form.fields_for :items do |item|
    = item.text_field :description
    = item.nhumber_field :quantity
```

Handling mapping whatever kind of crazy you're getting from that query to item instances is not the job of your view. It should be handled elsewhere such as the controller or a service object:

```
class InvoicesController
  def new  
    invoice_data = get_it_from_somewhere
    @invoice = Invoice.new do |i|
      invoice_data.each do |raw|
        i.items.new(
          description: data.position,
          # ...
        )
      end
    end   
  end

  def create 
    @invoice = Invoice.new(invoice_params)
    if @invoice.save
      redirect_to @invoice
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private 
  
  def invoice_params
    params.require(:invoice)
          .permit(:foo, :bar, items_attributes: [ :description, :quantity, ...])
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi Max. Thanks a lot for replying. Just to understand completely your lines of code, I have some newbie questions: do I have to create an Items model? or do I have to create an items column in Invoice model? ... because in this line `i.items.new(... ` I am getting this error: `uninitialized constant Invoices::Item` 

and last one:  form_with is an alternative or form_tag can be used as well? Thanks a lot again!

Comment: Yes, you should create an Item model.